# will urbanairship work with phonegap build android - only html,js files , no java files

Tags: android, cordova, urbanairship.com

Can i use urban airship for notifications in my app? 
My app uses phonegap build(only html, js files) . 
I think we need to place some java files for using urbanairship .

If possible, will inserting PushNotification.js in the head is sufficient or do i need to do other configs like config.xml etc .?

Comment: UA doesn't support phonegap build, but they do have a phonegap plugin. You'll simply need to add & build it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Urbanairship for notification. Please follow

https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

it works for android as well as IOS.

Thanks. Hope it helps.